Is my characterisation of KVM and QEMU accurate?
I usually write essays on topics I am studying to help my understanding. Below are excerpts from my study of Virtualisation. I would like comments from real professionals on their accuracy.

KVM is a software that provides primitives for a user to create hypervisors. KVM provides an interface for a user-space application (running as independent process(es), created by QEMU, KVMTool or even a simple custom program) to perform the actions of a hypervisor via the \dev\kvm device file and the associated KVM ioctls implemented by the kvm kernel module.


The role of KVM is to enable the implementation the “hypervisor emulation of a sensitive instruction”. This involves handling VM Exits via a specified exit handler for each exit reason (this is the instruction emulation when the CPU detects a sensitive instruction).

In other words, KVM is a virtualisation enabler that relies on the Intel VT-X hardware extension (i.e. the provisioning of root and non-root VMX modes), and a hypervisor is software that has code to handle/respond to VM Exits.
Specifically, is it accurate to characterise QEMU as a userspace application that both:

Implements VM-Exit Handlers that use KVM ioctls, i.e. is a hypervisor. (what happens if QEMU is used independently?)
Enables Virtual Machine (i.e. a stream of guest OS/application instructions) creation?


if qemu is used without kvm it will simulate the processor, which is slow
